# Fragments Garbage collection

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am using Fragments in my app and i have doubt that by adding and removing fragment every time, Is the fragment garbage collected when you remove it?

Here is my code :

in onCreate()

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.add(detailFragmentID, new MyDetailFragment());
 fragmentTransaction.add(fragmentID, new MyListFragmentt());
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

in onRestart()

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 Fragment previousFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(detailFragmentID);
 if (previousFragment != null) {
     fragmentTransaction.remove(previousFragment);
 }
 fragmentTransaction.add(detailFragmentID, new MyDetailFragment());
 fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Here when i go to some activity and come back onRestart will be called.

by adding and removing fragment every time, Is the fragment garbage collected here?

[Formatted the code properly]

Answer (score 1):

It would be tough to know if it was GC'd. I think what your really asking is whether the Fragment is **marked** for GC (i.e. will it get GC'd later).

The easiest way to check this is to put a break point in your Fragment's `onDestroy()` method and see if that ever gets called. You can feel confident that if the system "destroy"s your Fragment that it'll eventually get GC'd.

Comment: That last statement isn't quite true, is it? Once onDestroy() gets called, but 'this' of the fragment remains referenced somewhere the Fragment will not be GC'd. source: http://blog.nimbledroid.com/2016/05/23/memory-leaks.html

Comment: @Voy you are absolutely right. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`GC` will run on its own schedule unless you specifically call `finalize()` method on some `Object`. So, I think you don't need to worry about the `GC` here when you are removing a `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection will collect the objects automatically whenever there a need arrived by the  some of the resources and will collect the resources which are remained unused in memory.

Removing `Fragments` using remove method will only remove the fragment from its stack not from the memory. You can not be sure that `GC` will remove it at a time from memory as we call remove method of Fragment.

So by adding and removing `Fragment` every time, you can not say that it will always `GC` from memory.